# Website status always shows forbidden, what can i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

So I am doing a **JWT** for my website.
I defined a `verifyToken` function, also created 2 request endpoints.

I did everything right I think, but why it always shows Forbidden status?

**utilities/verify-token.js**

```
     function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
     const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
     if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
       const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
       const bearerToken = bearer[1];
       req.token = bearerToken;
       next();
     } else {
       res.sendStatus(403);
     }
 }

 module.exports = verifyToken;
```

**app.js**

```
    app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/profile/" + req.user.id);

    jwt.sign(req.user, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: '30s' }, (err, token) => {
      console.log(token)
    });
  }
);

app.get("/profile/:id", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.SECRET, (err, data) =>{
console.log(data)
})

 req.params.id = req.user.id;
let profile = await User.findById(req.params.id);

res.render("./profile/girisedildi", {
  user: req.user
});
});
```

Comment: Share the contents of `req.headers`

Comment: how can i do it lol

Comment: `console.log` usually

Comment: ```[Function : header ]```